# How to render react components by using map and join?

Tags: reactjs

I have one component which is going to display Array of String. The code looks like this:

```
React.createClass({
  render() {
     <div>
        this.props.data.map(t => <span>t</span>)
     </div>
  }
})
```

It is working perfectly fine.
i.e. if `props.data = ['tom', 'jason', 'chris']`, the rendered result in the page would be `tomjasonchris`.

Then, I want to join all the names by using comma, so I change the code to:

```
this.props.data.map(t => <span>t</span>).join(', ')
```

However, the rendered result is `[Object], [Object], [Object]`.

I don't know how to interpret object to become react components to be rendered. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `reduce()` without second argument and without spreading the previous result:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
     <div>
        {this.props.data
          .map(t => <span>{t}</span>)
          .reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])}
     </div>
  }
}
```

Without second argument, `reduce()` will [start at index 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of 0, and React is perfectly happy with nested arrays.

As said in the comments, you want to only use this for arrays with at least one item, because `reduce()` without second argument will throw with an empty array. Normally this should not be a problem, since you want to display a custom message saying something like 'this is empty' for empty arrays anyway.

**Update for Typescript**

You can use this in Typescript (without type-unsafe `any`) with a `React.ReactNode` type parameter on `.map()`:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
     <div>
        {this.props.data
          .map<React.ReactNode>(t => <span>{t}</span>)
          .reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])}
     </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: `If the array is empty and no initialValue was provided, TypeError would be thrown.`. so it won't work for empty array.

Comment: Note also that this recursively nests the `prev` array. e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` becomes `[[[1,",",2],",",3],",",4]`.

Comment: Thank you Eugene Krevenets, I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Tamlyn: Do you think my original mention of your point in the answer ('React is perfectly happy with nested arrays') is clear enough or should I elaborate on this?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. So, I guess not clear enough for me, at least :)

Comment: @MaartenterHorst I would elaborate a bit, I questioned my understanding of `Array.prototype.reduce` until I read the comments haha.

Comment: @MaartenterHorst What about the `key` attribute for React? (I'm using a `<Separator />` instead of a simple character)

Comment: Anyone made this solution work with React + TypeScript?

Comment: Second @MattDell's comment. Typescript complains

Comment: @MattDell Figured out that adding an initial value of an empty array TypeScript stops complaining, but then it adds the separator before the first value.

Comment: @Jstuff I eneded up having to use any. `.reduce((prev: JSX.Element, current: JSX.Element): any => [prev, (<span>&nbsp;</span>), current])`

Comment: A teammate pointed out this solution is not actually doing what we would like and is prone to breaking. I have posted a solution to the problem using `React.Fragment` that everyone should take a look at!

Comment: Building on @MattDell 's comment, I had to use `.reduce(((prev: JSX.Element, curr: JSX.Element): any => [prev, ", ", curr]) as any)}` (note the `as any`) for a Typescript solution.

Comment: What's the use of the square brackets [ ] in `.reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])}`

Comment: @kenold It’s an arrow function that returns an array. The “old” syntax would be `.reduce(function (prev, curr) { return [ prev, ', ', curr ]; })`

Comment: For TypeScript I found this solution: `.reduce((prev, curr) => <>{prev}, {curr}</>)`. It expected an `Element`, so I gave it an `Element` (which `Fragment` is one of). It's also more readable than a returned array.

Comment: Here goes working TS solution with fixed first comma:
```.reduce((acc: ReactNodeArray, current: ReactNode, index: number) => {
  return [...acc, index ? ', ' : '', current];
}, [])```

Comment: `[].concat(prev, ', ', next)` is perfectly solves the nested array issue.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `reduce` to combine multiple elements of an array:

```
React.createClass({
  render() {
     <div>
        this.props.data
        .map(t => <span>t</span>)
        .reduce((accu, elem) => {
            return accu === null ? [elem] : [...accu, ',', elem]
        }, null)
     </div>
  }
})
```

This initializes the accumulator with null, so we can wrap the first item in an array. For each following element in the array, we construct a new array that contains all previous elements using the `...-operator`, add the separator and then the next element.

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: thanks, exactly what I needed. You can remove the null check and ternary by initialising the accumulator as an empty array

Comment: @Larry if you remove the null check and ternary, and pass [] as the initializer, how do you avoid a leading comma? `['a'].reduce((a, e) => [...a, ',', e],[])` yields `[",", "a"]`.   Passing no initializer works unless the array is empty, in which case it returns a TypeError.

Comment: @Guy you're absolutely correct - my error was that I was joining values with spaces, and missing the empty span in the rendered output

Comment: I like this because it makes it explicit that you're relying on a null for the first item

Answer (score 32):

If I just want to render a comma-separated array of components, I usually find `reduce` too verbose. A shorter solution in such cases is

```
{arr.map((item, index) => (
  <Fragment key={item.id}>
    {index > 0 && ', '}
    <Item {...item} />
  </Fragment>
))}
```

`{index > 0 && ', '}` will render a comma followed by a space in front of all array items except the first one.

If you want to separate the second-to-last item and the last one by something else, say the string `' and '`, you can replace `{index > 0 && ', '}` with

```js
{index > 0 && index !== arr.length - 1 && ', '}
{index === arr.length - 1 && ' and '}
```

Comment: I like this, this solution is easiest to understand for a React newbie like me :)

Comment: You might more commonly see `<Fragment></Fragment>` as the shorthand `<></>`. In this case however the longer version must be used because each item in a list requires a unique `key`, and you can't add a `key` to `<></>`. However, you might not need `<Item>`, if `item` is already a component.

Comment: The point of `reduce` is to be able to deal with the whole set in one go without edge cases, so you don't have to worry about off by one errors. Also for React you have to get more verbose by introducing the `Fragment` component that you can avoid with reduce.

Answer (score 22):

**Update with React 16:** It's now possible to render strings directly, so you can simplify your code by removing all the useless `<span>` tags.

```
const list = ({ data }) => data.reduce((prev, curr) => [ prev, ', ', curr ]);
```

Comment: If data is empty, it will throw an error (cannot reduce an empty array without giving a default value).
However, you can make it work like that:
`.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev ? [prev, ', ', curr] : curr), null)}`

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer actually returns an array of arrays because `prev` will be an array each time. React is smart enough to make this work, but is it is prone to causing problems in the future such as breaking Reacts diffing algorithm when giving keys to each result of map.

The new `React.Fragment` feature lets us do this in an easy to understand manner without the underlying issues.

```
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
     <div>
        {this.props.data
          .map((t, index) => 
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <span> {t}</span> ,
            </React.Fragment>
          )
      </div>
  }
}
```

With `React.Fragment` we can simply place the separator `,` outside of the of the returned HTML and React won't complain.

Comment: Awesome solution, but you need to remove comma for last element of array

Comment: You can always use a turnery and the index to solve that.

Comment: You can remove last comma with this modification:                   <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    <span> {t}</span>
                    {index === this.props.data.length - 1 ? '' : ','}
                  </React.Fragment>

Comment: @JohnP It's easier to add it in front: `<React.Fragment key={index}>{index ? ',' : ''}<span>{t}</span></React.Fragment>`.

Answer (score 9):

the `<span>{t}</span>` you are returning is an object, not a string. Check the react docs about it https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform

By using `.join()` on the returned array from `map`, you are joining the array of objects. `[object Object], ...`

You can put the comma inside the `<span></span>` so it gets rendered the way you want it to.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.data.map(
            (t,i) => <span>{t}{ this.props.data.length - 1 === i ? '' : ','} </span>
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**sample:** https://jsbin.com/xomopahalo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 7):

My variant:

```
{this.props.data
    .map(item => <span>{item}</span>)
    .map((item, index) => [index > 0 && ', ', item ])}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using es6 you could do something like:

```js
const joinComponents = (accumulator, current) => [
  ...accumulator, 
  accumulator.length ? ', ' : '', 
  current
]
```

And then run:

```
listComponents
  .map(item => <span key={item.id}> {item.t} </span>)
  .reduce(joinComponents, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested array to keep "," outside.

```
  <div>
      {this.props.data.map((element, index) => index == this.props.data.length - 1 ? <span key={index}>{element}</span> : [<span key={index}>{element}</span>, ", "])}
  </div>
```

Optimize it by saving the data to array and modify last element instead of checking if its last element all the time.

```
  let processedData = this.props.data.map((element, index) => [<span key={index}>{element}</span>, ", "])
  processedData [this.props.data.length - 1].pop()
  <div>
      {processedData}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    {data.map( ( item, i ) => {
                  return (
                      <span key={i}>{item.propery}</span>
                    )
                  } ).reduce( ( prev, curr ) => [ prev, ', ', curr ] )}
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by Pith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459785/4465874), React 16 allow you to use strings directly so wrapping the strings in span tags are no longer needed. Building on [Maarten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788571/4465874), if you also want to deal with a custom message right away (and avoid throwing an error on empty array), you could lead the operation with a ternary if statement on the length property on the array. That could look something like this:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  const { data } = this.props;

  render() {
     <div>
        {data.length
          ? data.reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])
          : 'No data in the array'
        }
     </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return a flat array. Handle s case with non iterable first object by providing an initial empty array and filters the not needed first comma from the outcome

```
[{}, 'b', 'c'].reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, ', ', curr], []).splice(1) // => [{}, 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only who thinks there's a lot of needless spreading and nesting going on in the answers here? Points for being concise, sure, but it leaves the door open to issues of scale or React changing how they deal with nested arrays/Fragments.

```
const joinJsxArray = (arr, joinWith) => {
  if (!arr || arr.length < 2) { return arr; }

  const out = [arr[0]];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    out.push(joinWith, arr[i]);
  }
  return out;
};

// render()
<div>
  {joinJsxArray(this.props.data.map(t => <span>t</span>), ', ')}
</div>
```

One array, no nesting. No sexy method chaining either, but if you find yourself doing this often you can always add it to the array prototype or wrap it in a function that takes a mapping callback as well to do it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function YourComponent(props) {

  const criteria = [];

  if (something) {
    criteria.push(<strong>{ something }</strong>);
  }

  // join the jsx elements with `, `
  const elements = criteria.reduce((accu, elem) => {
    return accu === null ? [elem] : [...accu, ', ', elem]
  }, null);

  // render in a jsx friendly way
  return elements.map((el, index) => <React.Fragment key={ index }>{ el }</React.Fragment> );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `flatMap` (supported in all mainstream modern browsers as of June 2022), you can do it in a single step, something like this:

```js
const Demo = ({ data }) => <div>{data.flatMap(
    (t, i) => [...(i ? [', '] : []), <span key={i}>{t}</span>]
)}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<Demo data={['tom', 'jason', 'chris']} />, document.body)
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
span { color: firebrick; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If index == 0, the callback returns `[span]`; else, it returns `[text, span]`. Because we used `flatMap` instead of `map`, the resulting 2d array of `[[span], [text, span], [text, span]]` is flattened to `[span, text, span, text, span]`, which React can render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cool library called [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) to join your array element. Also lodash provides plethora of functionalities to work with arrays and many more.

Install lodash

```
npm i lodash
```

Import lodash to your component. It's a common practice to use "_" for lodash import.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

If you have an array you can join it like this. You can use any separator.

```
let data = ['tom', 'jason', 'chris'];

<div>{_.join(data, ",")}</div>
```

Hope this would help someone.

Answer (score -2):

```
{errors.username.map((e,k) => <span key={k}>{e} <br/></span>)}
```

easiest way i could find.

Comment: This answer could be improved with an explanation as to why it resolves the issue presented in the question. Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -3):

Simply add join() after map and put it inside tag:

```
<span>{this.props.data.map((item) => item).join(', ')}</span>
```

Comment: Surrounding it with `span` does not change the output `[Object], [Object], [Object]`

Answer (score -4):

As of React 17, you can simply:

```
<div>
  {[1, 2, 3].map((e, i) => <p key={i}>{e}</p>)}
</div>
```

And it will render as:

```html
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```