# Join JSX with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've got a situation where I have several labels, with separator arrows in between them - sort of like breadcrumbs.

The last label has no arrow after it.

This seems like a perfect situation for `.join()`, for example:

```
[1,2,3,4].join('->');  // "1->2->3->4"
```

But, the labels are JSX, and the join delimiter is JSX as well.

Since `.join()` expects a string delimiter and converts array elements to strings, it ends up like this:

```
[<div />, <div />].join(<hr />); // "[object Object][object Object][object Object]"
```

I've explored the `.reduce()` solution detailed in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577448/is-there-a-way-to-do-array-join-in-react) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034038/how-to-render-react-components-by-using-map-and-join) but it doesn't seem to work quite right either.  Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Can you stringify the JSX and then do the join? Check out [react-dom-server `renderToString`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring). It returns the generated html from the component.

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to work quite right either"* What's the problem? React elements are not strings, so you certainly cannot `.join` them.

Comment: Yes, that's the essence of the question :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a nice way that you can solve it with reduce:

```
React.createClass({
  render() {
     <div>
        this.props.data
        .map(t => <div/>)
        .reduce((accu, elem) => {
            return accu === null ? [elem] : [...accu, <hr />, elem]
        }, null)
     </div>
  }
})
```

Comment: Delete `' '` from `hr`.

Comment: Now it's great, +1

Comment: FWIW, that's the exact same solution as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35840806/218196

Comment: Aha, I had seen that but skipped over it since I assumed it was the same as the other reduce solves I had seen.  Trying out now, thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep, that's the trick.  I'll go upvote the other and mark mine as a dupe. Thank you!

Comment: The ternary is unnecessary, because in the absence of an explicit `initialValue` argument,  the "[accumulator will be equal to the first value in the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description)".