# How to using array.prototype.join in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to join all the names by using space

```
 const { author} = this.props;
        const authors= author.map((e, i) =>
            <div className="ck12 o6 b4" key={i}>
                <div className="authorlist">
                    <h4>{e.name}</h4>
```

The code looks like this. 
JohnTomJack 
I want John Tom Jack. I added e.name.join(" ") but code giving error join is not a function. I try [how to render react components by using map and join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034038/how-to-render-react-components-by-using-map-and-join/40788571#40788571) but I could not.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in the code snippet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good morning sir,

The function `join` is only applicable to an `Array`.
Learn more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join

THis function will join all the elements (in most of the cases, strings) from the array to a single string.

For your specific case since the author name is inside an object with the property name, you could do the following:

```
const authorNames = author.map(e => e.name).join(' ');
// authorNames will be now John Tom Jack
```

You will use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) method to transform that array to a new array containing only strings. Then you can join those strings with the join function.

```js
// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const names = [{ name: 'John'}, {name: 'Doe'}, {name: 'Snow'}];
    console.log('names', names);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{names.map(e => e.name).join(' ')}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.